# How can I delete my user data programmatically in Safari | OSX?

Tags: bash, safari

I've found out how to do this in Firefox

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/
```

This command deletes my history, bookmarks, cookies, and probably much more.

I tried

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Safari/
```

for Safari but I will still logged in ( cookies still there ) after running it.

I prefer not to use the GUI.

Comment: I don't think you need sudo to remove files in your user directory?

Comment: Safari cookies are in `~/Library/Cookies`. Also, make sure that Safari isn't running when you do this, otherwise it will save its cookies again when you quit.

Comment: See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5196860?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: All the above comments are correct and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

All the comments below the answer has provided the right answer.
Im just collecting all the pieces and placing it here so others can benefit and have a full answer if they are having the same question.

---

[***`This post`***](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5196860/) supply the answer.

**Safari caches cookies in memory, so if you delete those files while it's still running and then quit, they'll be written back to disk.**

You must have safari closed in order to be sure that the cookies are deleted.

Once Safari is closed you can delete the following folders:

```bash
# delete the current user cookies
/Users/shortUserName/Library. 

# Or this path is the same as the above. both are the %HOME% directory
# of the current user 
~/Library should work.

# Other folders to remove as well:
~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage/
~/Library/WebKit/LocalStorage/
$TMPDIR/com.appleWebKit.WebContent+com.apple.Safari
```